# Java class method access

Tags: java, class

Back into Java but i'm lost on some basic referencing

If i have for example:
how do i refer to method test2 or test3 from within method problem within class b?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class zz{

a1=new a();

// i can do 

a1.b1.test();

public test2()
{
} 

}

public class a{

b b1= new b()

public test3()
{
}

}


public class b{

public test()
{

}

public problem()
{
// but how do i refer to method test2 or test3 from here?

something like

zz.test2();

zz.a1.test3();

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method from another class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757047/how-to-call-a-method-from-another-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can make method of class a static to invoke it like this :

```
a.test3();
```

or create instance of object a to invoke itlike this :

```
public problem {
  a objA = new a();
  a.test();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't but i don't see any limitation why it should not be. It doesn't access any object variables, so it can be called in static context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the object before using it to call the methods. You can only call static methods directly with the class name.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public problem()
{
    // but how do i refer to method test2 or test3 from here?
    zz zObj = new zz();
    b bObj = new b();
    zObj.test2();
    bObj.test3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you first create `ZZ` object then you can access everything from that class like below

```
public problem()
{
ZZ zz = new ZZ();

zz.test2();

zz.a1.test3();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in code

1.Method should have return type I have not seen in your code

2.Proper Naming conventions has to be followed like class name should start with `Capital` letters

Make changes in your code as below

```
     public class Zz{

        A a1=new A();

        // i can do 

        a1.b1.test();

        public void test2()
        {
        } 

        }
        //End of class Zz
        public class A{

        B b1= new B()

        public void  test3()
        {
        }

        }

        //End of class A
        public class B{

        public void test()
        {

        }

        public void problem()
        {
        // but how do i refer to method test2 or test3 from here?

         Zz zz = new Zz();
         //create  instance of A 
         A a=new A();
         zz.test2();
         a.test3();

        }

        }
//End of class B
```